Chrome DevTools Debugger freezing once it hits breakpoint
I have recently started working on a ReactJS webapp codebase that is bit out-dated and currently being tasked to modernize by upgrading to latest versions of dependencies and NodeJS 14 to LTS.
The problem I encounter is that sometimes, the Chrome Devtools debugger would freeze once it has hit the breakpoint, sometimes I will be able to see the stack trace calculated but cannot interact with the debugger anymore as it becomes unresponsive (even if I use keyboard shortcut F8 to try and resume)
One of my suspicion is that somehow it sees 2 folders in the Page > top > localhost:3000
I tried putting the 1st folder (C:/Dev/IntelliJ/xxx/src) into ignore list since those src files are misleading, ie. if you put breakpoints to those files, the debugger never hits them since the debugger is only looking at the 2nd folder (static/js)

However, I even if I put this in the ignore list, the debugger is still encountering freezing and would require me to close the tab itself as its unresponsive.
My chrome versions is up-to-date Version 127.0.6533.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Any help please?

The same issue occurs for me. it might be due to new version of chrome

that's interesting to hear, you have the same version 127.0.6533.89?

Yes the exact same 127.0.6533.89 version

There is a new version 127.0.6533.100. the issue is fixed in it.

i updated from 127.0.6533.89 to  127.0.6533.100 and still having the same issue

Same here, last version of chrome on a ReactApp (but don't know if it is related to React). On startup after pressing F12, DevTools seems to freeze for a long time, as if it goes into some infinite loop or something, as its cpu consumption is pretty high.

By the way, as a workaround, Chrome canary (v.128) seems to work fine

Thanks Julien, hopefully our company software gets this v128 soon, I cannot force install and have to wait for company rollout

finally got v128.0.6613.85 from company policy and works now

I had the same problem, just upgraded to v129.0.6668.58 which also fixes it.

Had this issue as well, I update to Chrome v.128.xxx.xxx. today (27th august) and no more errors. Check if your browser is equal or greater than this version.

finally got v128.0.6613.85 from company policy and works now

I am developing a React app and using Chrome's debugger. When I click in the source code area, the debugger freezes. It seems like there is a timeout. After a while, the debugger works fine. Until the next freeze after a page reload.
I cannot confirm that updating to the current version of Google Chrome (127.0.6533.100) will fix the problem.

There is an update to version 127.0.6533.120 for Google Chrome. But it will not fixes the problem. But the tip with Google Chrome Canary in the comments above works. Chrome Canary is installed in addition to Chrome.

My team is having the same problems.  Able to use F12 to take the debugger down, and again to bring it back, the console works, but breakpoints seem to cause some sort of timeout.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
